# How do encrypt the request payload in network tab?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-deployment, react-fullstack

currently iam using react + nodejs.
How do encrypt the request payload in the network tab?
How do hide the preview and response data in the network tab?

[sample request link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bk4R.png)

Comment: My suggestions: Don't. It's decrypted in the browser anyway and anyone with minimal debugging skills can see the data either way. You could base64 encode/decode the data which makes it "seem" encrypted and harder for unexperienced people to see the data you're sending. About completely hiding the response preview in the network tab: You can't.